# How to assign a negative exponent value to double variable?

Tags: c#, types, syntax

```
d double;
f float;
d = 4.4e38;//±3.4e38 is maximum value of float
f = (float)d;
Console.WriteLine("f = (float)d is " + f);//op is Infinity
d = -2.5E−45;    
f = (float)d;
Console.WriteLine("f = (float)d is " + f);//expected op is zero
```

My query: d = -2.5E−45;this LOC is giving compile error, please tell me the right way to assign this value in double variable

EDIT:
yes, you were right, once I corrected minus sign my code starts running.;±1.5e−45 is minimum value of float. When I'm assigning value -2.5e-45 to d, which is outside the lower range, then casting double to float should have given me result as ZERO, but result is -2.802597e-45, Why?

[**msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yht2cx7b.aspx**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yht2cx7b.aspx) in this page remarks number 4 states that if double is too big to fit into float, casting results into INFINITY, and if too small then results into ZERO. Here in my code sample I'm trying checking these two conditions, by taking such values that it creates a case of INFINITY and ZERO after casting. Please correct me if I have not taken appropriate value of variable d to create a case for ZERO, as outcome.

Comment: That is the correct way to define a negative exponent.

Comment: your are trying to convert double to float which exceed the limit of float also.

Comment: Why do you think the result should be zero? See [float reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/b1e65aza.aspx).

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yht2cx7b.aspx     in this page remarks number 4 states that if double is too big to fit into float ,casting results into INFINITY, and if too small then results into ZERO. here in my code sample I'm trying checking these two conditions , by taking such values that it creates a case of INFINITY and ZERO after casting,Plz correct me if I have not taken appropriate value of variable d to create a case for ZERO ,as outcome.